# How I can index the array starting from 1 instead of zero?

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {

  Products[] products = reports[i].getDecisions;

  for (int j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {

  }
}
```

Here I want to index the inner for loop starting from 1 , but it is not working as expected, I also changed the j

Comment: Index in java starts from zero only,

Comment: Invent your own programming language :)

Comment: `not working as expected` - what did you expected and how it differs?

Comment: Why do you want it to start from `1`?

Comment: there are many old programming languages that used to start with 1 or probably he read an algorithm book where the assume the starting index to be 1.

Comment: If it comes to 0, then add 1 to get ones instead of zeros. That's cool algorithm.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Java arrays are always 0-based. You can't change that behavior. You can fill or use it from another index, but you can't change the base index.

It's defined in [JLS §10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4), if you are interested in it.

> A component of an array is accessed by an array access expression (§15.13) that consists of an expression whose value is an array reference followed by an indexing expression enclosed by [ and ], as in A[i].
>
> All arrays are 0-origin. An array with length n can be indexed by the integers 0 to n-1.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do that as array index in Java starts from 0.
But you can access array with index 1 with little modifications.

Example:
Consider an integer array "a" with length n

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

This can be modified as:

```
int a[] = new int[n+1];
for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like in most languages arrays are indexed from 0. You better get used to it, there is no workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Base Index of Java arrays is always **0**. It cannot be changed to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers, to jump to a certain point of the array and start the array from there.

For example:

```
char str[20];
str={'H', 'E' ,'L' ,'L', 'O','W' ,'O ','R','L',' D'};
char *ptr;
*ptr=str[0];
//right now its pointing to the starting.
ptr=ptr+3;
//Now pointing at 3rd unit.
```

This doesn't work in every compiler.This is the closest thing that can be done for your question.

Comment: I found this following a link/reference you provided on a different question. For that I propose to edit this one to make it more assertive. "This doesn't work in every compiler, I guess." does not help with giving the impression of a well-researched, confident, portable and reliable solution.

Comment: Actually, if you look differently, stating loopholes/problems in a your solution is the only reliability you have in life. In Engineering, everything is improved upon by looking at its flaw and not its perfection. So I am stating beforehand that this technique doesn't work for all compilers, is a blessing in disguise.

Comment: Pointing out assumptions, actually being aware of them too, and admitting shortcomings is a rare gift in engineers. I do not trust people who are always right, or think so. So I am fully with you on that part.

Comment: so you are arguing in sake of putting me down?

Comment: I cannot parse the phrasing of that comment of yours.

Comment: By the way after `*ptr=str[0];` I would expect that the memory the non-initialised `ptr` points to now contains the value `'H'`, i.e. 0x47. `ptr` is however still not pointing to any legally accessable memory. So "right now its pointing to the starting." is something you could discuss as one of the more questionable things among your statements. Then `ptr=ptr+3` has it pointing to a slightly different, not legally accessable memory. But I get the impression that your "This doesn't work in every compiler." does not refer to that and is a more general "Don't blame me for not testing this."

Comment: But of course, I might be totally wrong with everything I wrote. In that case please explain your answer in more detail. Explain which parts might not work on every compiler and especially why. Or better which parts might actually work on any compiler.

Answer (score 0):

its all simple that in C , C++ , Java or etc.. the array index start from "0" only. and we can't change it. but sometimes in some Practice problems we are asked to use 1-indexed-based array, which we actually can't do that, so to tackle that, just leave 0th-index aside, and start using the array from 1th-index onwards, and while solving the situation always keep in mind that we have to never include or use that 0th-index in our operations.

Comment: This is basically what the accepted answer says: "You can fill or use it from another index, but you can't change the base index."

Comment: yaa both means same only.... as my answer is mostly dedicated to newbies... so let them understand clearly.